# Calculate Months separated (oracle 11G)

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Dear Respectful Experts,

We have a table having Column TOTAL_MONTHS e.g. if

As shown below table need to Update using Update Statement.

TOTAL_MONTHS = 15 then Update the Column named "Months<=12" = 12 and Update the Column named "Months>12" = 3

another example in below table is
TOTAL_MONTHS =8 then Update Column named "Months<=12" = 8 and Update Column named "Months>12" = 0

| Title | Amount | Total_months | Months<=12 | Months>12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10101288 | 28000 | 15 | 12 | 3 |
| 10101289 | 40000 | 13 | 12 | 1 |
| 10101290 | 2000000 | 10 | 10 | 0 |
| 10101291 | 50000 | 14 | 12 | 2 |
| 10101239 | 6000 | 11 | 11 | 0 |
| 10101240 | 50000 | 8 | 8 | 0 |
| 10121003 | 690 | 12 | 12 | 0 |

```
CREATE TABLE "TEST3"       
   (  TITLE VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),     
  AMOUNT NUMBER,     
  Total_Months NUMBER,     
  Months<=12 NUMBER,     
  Months>12 NUMBER    
   )  

REM INSERTING into TEST3
Insert into TEST3 (TITLE,AMOUNT,"Total_Months","Months<=12","Months>12") values ('10101288',28000,15,null,null);
Insert into TEST3 (TITLE,AMOUNT,"Total_Months","Months<=12","Months>12") values ('10101289',40000,13,null,null);
Insert into TEST3 (TITLE,AMOUNT,"Total_Months","Months<=12","Months>12") values ('10101290',2000000,10,null,null);
Insert into TEST3 (TITLE,AMOUNT,"Total_Months","Months<=12","Months>12") values ('10101291',50000,14,null,null);
Insert into TEST3 (TITLE,AMOUNT,"Total_Months","Months<=12","Months>12") values ('10101239',6000,11,null,null);
Insert into TEST3 (TITLE,AMOUNT,"Total_Months","Months<=12","Months>12") values ('10101240',50000,8,null,null);
Insert into TEST3 (TITLE,AMOUNT,"Total_Months","Months<=12","Months>12") values ('10121003',690,12,null,null);
```

Somebody can help us please.

Thanks,

Regards,

Out Put Result as below

| Title | Amount | Total_months | Months<=12 | Months>12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10101288 | 28000 | 15 | 12 | 3 |
| 10101289 | 40000 | 13 | 12 | 1 |
| 10101290 | 2000000 | 10 | 10 | 0 |
| 10101291 | 50000 | 14 | 12 | 2 |
| 10101239 | 6000 | 11 | 11 | 0 |
| 10101240 | 50000 | 8 | 8 | 0 |
| 10121003 | 690 | 12 | 12 | 0 |

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEAST` and `GREATEST`:

```
update test3
set "Months<=12" = LEAST(total_months, 12),
    "Months>12" = GREATEST(total_months - 12, 0);
```

The same can be done with `CASE` expressions of course.

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/wB89f9eN

I don't consider it a good idea to store these calculated values in common table columns, by the way. Don't store data redundantly in a database. What would it mean, if some day you find a row containing total_months = 15, "Months<=12" = 12, "Months>12" = 10? Which value would be correct, which not? If you want to see the results like if they were table columns for convenience, use [generated columns](https://database.guide/how-to-create-a-generated-column-in-oracle/) or a [view](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_8004.htm#SQLRF01504) instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate the months as full-years and part-years or as up-to-one year and more-than-one-year then you can calculate those values and do not need to have separate columns in the database that run the risk of becoming out of sync.

If you did want to represent the values in the table then you can use virtual columns:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "TEST3"(
  TITLE            VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  AMOUNT           NUMBER,     
  Total_Months     NUMBER,     
  Full_Year_Months NUMBER
                   GENERATED ALWAYS AS (Total_months - MOD(total_months, 12)),
  Part_Year_Months NUMBER
                   GENERATED ALWAYS AS (MOD(total_months, 12)),
  "Month>12"       NUMBER
                   GENERATED ALWAYS AS (GREATEST(total_months-12,0)),
  "Month<=12"      NUMBER
                   GENERATED ALWAYS AS (LEAST(total_months,12))
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
Insert into TEST3 (TITLE,AMOUNT,Total_Months) values ('10101288',  28000,15);
Insert into TEST3 (TITLE,AMOUNT,Total_Months) values ('10101289',  40000,13);
Insert into TEST3 (TITLE,AMOUNT,Total_Months) values ('10101290',2000000,10);
Insert into TEST3 (TITLE,AMOUNT,Total_Months) values ('10101291',  50000,14);
Insert into TEST3 (TITLE,AMOUNT,Total_Months) values ('10101239',   6000,11);
Insert into TEST3 (TITLE,AMOUNT,Total_Months) values ('10101240',  50000, 8);
Insert into TEST3 (TITLE,AMOUNT,Total_Months) values ('10121003',    690,12);
Insert into TEST3 (TITLE,AMOUNT,Total_Months) values ('12345678',1234567,45);
```

Then the table contains:

| TITLE | AMOUNT | TOTAL_MONTHS | FULL_YEAR_MONTHS | PART_YEAR_MONTHS | Month>12 | Month<=12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10101288 | 28000 | 15 | 12 | 3 | 3 | 12 |
| 10101289 | 40000 | 13 | 12 | 1 | 1 | 12 |
| 10101290 | 2000000 | 10 | 0 | 10 | 0 | 10 |
| 10101291 | 50000 | 14 | 12 | 2 | 2 | 12 |
| 10101239 | 6000 | 11 | 0 | 11 | 0 | 11 |
| 10101240 | 50000 | 8 | 0 | 8 | 0 | 8 |
| 10121003 | 690 | 12 | 12 | 0 | 0 | 12 |
| 12345678 | 1234567 | 45 | 36 | 9 | 33 | 12 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9I0rGHPP)